# Getting the 'Start Tag Expected' error in R

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to parse a XML file using RStudio. Here are few lines of my file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iaapi:Project name="IA Quickstart" xmlns:iaapi="http://www.ibm.com/investigate/api/iaapi">
<DataRuleDefinition name="DRD_dummy_rule">
<ExecutableRules>`

I used the function xmlParse() to parse the file, but am getting the following error: Start tag expected.'<' not found'

But as we can see we have the '<' tag in the beginning of the xml string. Help is greatly appreciated.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. My code was:

```
xml = xmlTreeParse("data-raw/documentos.xml", useInternalNodes=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8)
```

My solution was:

```
txt = readLines("data-raw/documentos.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")
xml = xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

Apparently when read `documentos.xml` the first line has a stranger character `<U+FEFF>`, that I believe to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to solve this error: `Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  :    Start tag expected, '<' not found [4]`