# reading and parsing xml files with a loop

Tags: r, xml

i have the following xml files in a folder. Manually if i want to read them and parse them i need to do the following two chunks:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.15")
BiocManager::install("biocLite")
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.15")
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("KEGGgraph")
if(!require(xml2)){
    install.packages("xml2")
    library(xml2)
}
if(!require(XML)){
    install.packages("XML")
    library(XML)
}
library(KEGGgraph)
library(xml2)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(methods)
```

```
Aml<- read_xml("Acute myeloid leukemia.xml")
Nsclc<- read_xml("Non-small cell lung cancer.xml")
Sclc <-read_xml("Small cell lung cancer.xml")
Brcan <-read_xml("Breast cancer.xml")
```

```
Aml_parsed <- parseKGML2Graph(Aml, genesOnly=FALSE)
Nsclc_parsed<- parseKGML2Graph(Nsclc, genesOnly=FALSE)
Sclc_parsed <-parseKGML2Graph(Sclc, genesOnly=FALSE)
Brcan_parsed <-parseKGML2Graph(Brcan, genesOnly=FALSE)
```

What i want to ask is how can i build a functionn that will do the previous automatically?
I tried the following to read them but it doesnt work as i want

```
cancer_data_xml<- list.files(pattern = "*.xml")
list_of_cancer_data <- as.list(cancer_data_xml)
```

Can you please suggest me something in order not to have to do it all this manually one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the xml and making the graph for each file individually, you can use iteration to perform all of the tasks simultaneously. The R code would look something like this:

```r
xml_files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.xml"),
  function(x) {parseKGML2Graph(read_xml(x))})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after applying what you said i get the following error  Error in read_xml.character(x) : Start tag expected, '<' not found [4]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942722/getting-the-start-tag-expected-error-in-r If not, please experiment and see if it works on some of the files and not others, and send the file for one of them that does not work.

Comment: apparently it doesnt work for any file...

Comment: you can download one file from here https://www.genome.jp/pathway/hsa05225

Comment: i tried this   txt = readLines("C:/Users/jimikardi/Desktop/cancer xml data/Pancreatic cancer.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")
xml = xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
xml_files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "Pancreatic cancer.xml"),
  function(x) {Pancan_parsed<- parseKGML2Graph(read_xml(x), genesOnly=FALSE)})

Comment: it reads it but it doesnt create the list as when i do manually. the most important is that it create a list of 1 but when i do it manually is a list of 2 which is the correct

Comment: Can you convert it into a list of two by going `xml_files[[1]]`? If not, can you send both outputs?

Comment: now that i tried it basically they are the same with this difference. with your function it does it a list of 1 and if i do it manually is a formal class graphnel. Do   you know what is this difference?

Comment: I would have to see a picture as I cannot download the packages with my version of R. Most likely, my list version is just a formal class graphnel, inside a list, so you have to access the graphnel with indexing.

Comment: it seems the same but then we go back to the initial problem which is that it cant read all files but one.

Comment: What if you just do `xml_files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.xml"), read_xml)`. Is there still an error, or is the error with the KGBB graph part.

Comment: Glad to hear it, let me know if you need anything else. There is a green check mark, if this solves your question.